# move plone site to subfolder without changing modification date

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

I have multiple plone sites in one zope instance (ZODB).
Now I'd like to move some of the sites to a subfolder.
The problem is that when I move the site the modification date of all the pages inside the site are getting updated.
Is there a way to prevent this so that the dates stay the same?

Comment: You may try a proper ZEXP export/import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving Plone sites in the ZMI isn't actually supported. It's unfortunately still possible to do this in the UI.

Various internal data structures inside the Plone site will break as a result of this. For example all catalogs will have invalid data (which can be fixed by reindexing the entire site) but also data structures inside the automatic redirection machinery will break without an easy way to fix them.

Also adding Plone sites anywhere except in the Zope root is generally discouraged. We are likely to disallow any nested folder structures in a future Plone version.

Comment: if it is discouraged to add a plone site anywhere else then the zope root doesn't this mean it will also be discouraged to use multiple data.fs files like [here](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/multiple-plone-sites-per-zope-instance-using-separate-data-fs-files-for-each-one)

Comment: Multiple Data.fs files work fine and will continue to do so. They are handled by our Zope root create site / upgrade overview screens already.

Answer (score 3):

Your best chance is to export the site (via the ZMI) then import into the folder. The target folder must be a Zope folder -- not a Plone folder or site. Make absolutely sure to reindex after the import. Hanno's warnings in his answer still apply.